# How would you programmatically report which Windows Services are not running?

Tags: powershell

Given:

- PowerShell 5.1 or above
- Cmdlet Get-Service
- Windows OS
- Windows Services

How would you programmatically report if a Window Services is Stopped?

[image]

Comment: `Get-Service |Where Status -ne Running`

Comment: How would I iterate that list and start them?

Comment: `Get-Service |Where Status -ne Running |Start-Service`

Comment: Thanks, if you add your answer to answers, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start them all, use the `Where-Object` cmdlet to filter the list of services so you only get those that:

- Are not running, and
- Are not disabled

Then pipe the resulting set of services to `Start-Service`:

```
Get-Service |Where-Object Status -ne Running |Where-Object StartType -ne Disabled |Start-Service
```

Comment: Would `Get-Service | Where-Object {($_.Status -ne Running) -and ($_.StartType -ne Disabled)} | Start-Service` be equivalent (or perhaps more efficient)?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin It will fail with a syntax error ;-) But even if you fix the string quoting, does it matter? You're going to have no more than a few hundred services, at most, the overhead from pipeline binding is going to be so negligible it'll never have a significant impact

Comment: Worth noting that `Where-Object PropertyName -eq $Value` is generally faster than `Where-Object { $_.PropertyName -eq $Value }`